Installed node and stuck with wallet error
I'm using this link https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet/ And All is done except this step "cabal install cardano-wallet" When i try to execute it all i get is. picture attaced. 
Something about extra/Plutus missing. What is this? and how to move forward?
Thanks
